# updatedb.conf, Ignore files using pattern match/globbing

Tags: wildcards, locate

Running `locate` command with a file name returns multiple entries as,

```
a.py
a.pyc
a.py~
```

Obviously, i am not looking for binaries/compiled files. I tried to configure `locate` command to ignore files that has pattern *.pyc, *.py~. [Man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/updatedb.conf) shows, locate command doesn't have globbing option.

How can one configure locate command to ignore files that match a pattern?

Comment: I am confused, since when did python scripts become binaries/compiled files?

Comment: when i said binaries/compiled files, i meant .pyc files and not .py scripts

Comment: There are several implementations of locate and they have different capabilities. Which one are you using? (e.g. GNU locate, mlocate, …)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried 'man locate'? If you were to examine the manual for the locate tool you will see that using '\' disables globbing and forces a literal pattern match.